# How to add specific style to column in selected row DataGrid GWT

Tags: css, gwt, datagrid

Im set custom CssResource for DataGrid.

First column in table is ordered column with specific style. 
So when row is selected i need set another specific style for the order column.

Something like that:

[image]

Comment: im trying .class.class method `.dataGridKeyboardSelectedRowCell.specificStyle{
    background-color: #444444 !important;
}` but is not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `.getCellStyleNames` method for your column:

```
Column<Object, String> numberColumn = new Column<Object, String>(new TextCell()) {

    @Override
    public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, Object object) {

    if (selectionModel.isSelected(object)) {
        return "boldStyle";
    }
};
```

Comment: It's work pretty. Thanks, but not work with `NoSelectionModel`.

Comment: You said in your question "when a row is selected". It does not matter how you decide if a row is selected - replace selectionModel.isSelected() with whatever you use.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [AbstractHasData#addCellPreviewHandler()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#addCellPreviewHandler%28com.google.gwt.view.client.CellPreviewEvent.Handler%29).

```
dataGrid.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<T>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
        if ("click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            table.getRowElement(event.getIndex()).getCells().getItem(0).getStyle()
                    .setBackgroundColor("#444444");
        }
    }

});
```

Note: This code is for `SingleSelectionModel`. If you need it for `MultiSelectionModel` then do same thing for all selected rows.

Comment: If you have a selection model, you can simply add a SelectionChangeHandler.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin How to get `TableCellElement` in `SelectionChangeHandler` to change the style?

Comment: Actually, there is a simpler solution. See my answer.

Comment: it's not work? because I use tag "!important" for style. How set style with this tag in code?